# Deadlock with no user code

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013, deadlock

I'm getting a deadlock in my C++ program, which used std::thread, std::mutex, std::condition_variable, etc.

There's nothing in itself strange about that, until I look at the stacks for each of the threads in my process:

```
8532    0   Main Thread Main Thread msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::ExternalContextBase::Block   Normal
                        ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForSingleObject@12()    
                        KernelBase.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectEx@12()   
                        kernel32.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation@12()   
                        msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::ExternalContextBase::Block() Line 145     
                        ntdll.dll!_ZwQueryVirtualMemory@24()     
                        kernel32.dll!_BasepFillUEFInfo@8()   
                        ntdll.dll!_ZwQueryInformationProcess@20()    
                        msvcr120.dll!_initterm(void (void) * * pfbegin, void (void) * * pfend) Line 954
```

-

```
6484    0   Worker Thread   ntdll.dll!_TppWaiterpThread@4() ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20  Normal
                        ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20()     
                        ntdll.dll!_TppWaiterpThread@4()  
                        kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()   
                        ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  
                        ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

-

```
6296    0   Worker Thread   msvcr120.dll!_threadstartex msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::ExternalContextBase::Block   Normal
                        ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForSingleObject@12()    
                        KernelBase.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectEx@12()   
                        kernel32.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation@12()   
                        msvcr120.dll!Concurrency::details::ExternalContextBase::Block() Line 145     
                        msvcp120.dll!std::_Thrd_startX(struct _Thrd_imp_t *,unsigned int (*)(void *),void *)     
                        msvcr120.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 376   
                        msvcr120.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Line 354     
                        kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()   
                        ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  
                        ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

None of the threads seem to be executing my code, and I know for a fact that we had already entered main, since the program had done some stuff before hanging.

I'm using the following class to communicate with my std::thread, in case I made some mistake there:

```
template <typename T>
class BlockingQueue
{
public:
    BlockingQueue() : _active(true) {}

    bool Get(T& out)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        _cv.wait(lock, [&](){ return !_queue.empty() || !_active; });

        if (_queue.empty())
        {
            assert(!_active);

            return false;
        }

        out = std::move(_queue.front());
        _queue.pop();

        return true;
    }

    void Put(const T& in)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

            _queue.push(in);
        }

        _cv.notify_one();
    }

    void Put(T&& in)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

            _queue.push(std::move(in));
        }

        _cv.notify_one();
    }

    void Finish()
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

            _active = false;
        }

        _cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    bool _active;
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    std::queue<T> _queue;
};
```

I have two ideas right now:

1. Main has already exited for some reason. This is a PoC, so when there's an error we log to stdout and call exit() (Yeah I know, not the greatest, this is being adapted from another C-style program written in C++). I do not see anything being logged to the terminal, but I suppose it's possible that the output was being buffered and hasn't been written out yet?
2. The debugger is lying to me in some way. Usually it puts in `[frames below may be missing/incorrect]` into the stack trace when it does this, but maybe it can happen without that.

Comment: You should notify inside mutex locks or you may encounter races:

1. `_cv.wait()` evaluates the predicate; it returns `false`
2. `notify_all` is called
3. `wait(lock)` is called in `_cv.wait()`

Not sure if that is the problem though.

Comment: I was looking at the documentation of std::condition_variable on cppreference.com, and it seemed to say that you didn't need to hold the lock while notifying, and in fact doing so was a performance pessimization (which makes sense, since any thread waking up due to the notify would immediately attempt to grab the lock and fail)

Comment: "The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock. However, some implementations (in particular many implementations of pthreads) recognize this situation and avoid this "hurry up and wait" scenario by transferring the waiting thread from the condition variable's queue directly to the queue of the mutex within the notify call, without waking it up. " is what they say.

Comment: Put some debug logs in your function, and see where it ends

Comment: Well, it depends on the situation. But I checked C++11 for `condition_variable::wait` and it says the lock is reaquired before each call to the predicate so it indeed cannot race for `_active`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was failing to replace an item in a queue, causing my thread to deadlock on retrieving from the queue, which means that the debugger was lying to me. :(