# How to tell when the debugger is lying to you

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Please take a look at my recent question here: [Deadlock with no user code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373904/deadlock-with-no-user-code)

How can you tell when the debugger is lying to you in this way? Other than, of course, showing that what it is telling you is impossible?

I don't like relying on that since I've seen so many 'impossible' states in a program that were in fact happening due to some subtle or esoteric problem.

Comment: Please don't make a question (outside of [meta]) that refers to another question in a link. Copy the relevant text here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Is it the fear that the other question is deleted /modified?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are pretty wacky stack traces, particularly the 1st one.  Hard to theorize how that happened.  It doesn't usually get that screwed up unless you debug optimized code.

Which is hint #1, never trust what the debugger tells you when you *have* to debug release built code.  Strongly avoid it, you don't always have the luxury when you need to troubleshoot a deadlock however.

Strong hint #2 is paying attention to the code-flow.  The normal one for a blocked thread, bottom to top in the Call Stack window, is yourcode => runtime (msvr120) => winapi layer (kernel32 et al) => native api (ntdll.dll).  This is generally the case, there are a few cases where this flow is reversed, callbacks from the OS into your code, like window notification, thread-start (always at the far bottom of the stack for example), I/O completion.

Which is what's wacky, there is no realistic scenario where a low-level native api function like ZwWaitForSingleObject() could ever directly call into the C runtime library.  That's bogus, only the top entry (Block) could be accurate.  Yes, tough debugging that way.

Comment: Yeah, it was code compiled in release mode. I wish the debugger would just tell me that it wasn't sure (although that may not be feasible to implement, or cause way too many false positives, I guess)